# Rails how to return a list of answers with a specific question_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, list, return

Let's say I have two Models, Answers and Questions (there are others, but irrelevant to the question). The models are as follows:

Answer.rb

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :question_id
  has_one :question, :through => :user, :dependent => :destroy
  validates :description, :presence => true
end
```

Question.rb

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :budget, :description, :headline, :user_id, :updated_at, :created_at
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :answers
  validates :headline, :description, :user_id, :presence => true 
end
```

I'd like to display on a page a list of all answers associated with a question, and only those questions.

I got this far. I believe this variable finds all the questions in the database by the question_id (foreign key):

```
@findanswers = Answer.all(params[:question_id])
```

And this one grabs the the id of the current question (this code will reside as an ERB on the page where the current question is located):

```
@questionshow = Question.find(params[:id])
```

And now I'm stuck. How do I put the two together so that I list all the answers with the current question id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need a route for `question.answers` which you can achieve with (in config/routes.rb)

```
resources :questions
  resources :answers
end
```

Then in your view you can do

```
<% @questionshow.answers.each do |answer| %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should rather be

```
@findanswers = Question.find(params[:question_id]).answers
```

but you have to decide if the "question id" is represented by `params[:id]` or `params[:question_id]`